# Is it necessary to enqueue jquery?

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

Is it necessary to enqueue jquery? I think sometring is wrong because it won't work without adding this line

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

I do not think I needed before I am pretty sure jquery is already in the wordpress core.

```
 function mis_cursos_all_user_scripts()  
    {  
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    // defer o async
    add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'mscrss_add_defer_attribute', 10, 2    );
    wp_register_script('vimeo', 'https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js', array(),'jquery'); 
    // error test is not enqueued in video pages! ojo
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mis_cursos_user_scripts_video', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'mis-cursos-videos.js', array( 'vimeo'), null, false  ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mis_cursos_user_scripts_test', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'mis-cursos-test.js', array( 'jquery'), null, false  ); 
    wp_localize_script( 'mis_cursos_user_scripts_video', 'mis_cursos_video_namespace', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );           
    wp_localize_script( 'mis_cursos_user_scripts_test', 'mis_cursos_test_namespace', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );     
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mis_cursos_all_user_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all. The 3rd argument of [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) is the script's dependencies. All you have to do, is to pass jquery to it, and WordPress will automatically enqueue jQuery for you.

Comment: But, I did it ,  see this line here:  wp_enqueue_script( 'mis_cursos_user_scripts_test', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'mis-cursos-test.js', array( 'jquery'), null, false  );

Comment: You are right. Now it works after updating Wordpress. Maybe the failure was caused by some error Beta testing Wordpress in my local server. Thanks.